# How do I solve this Pagination Error with Laravelapi

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-api

I am trying to send posts to Laravel Api. and I want to paginate them and also arrange them according to the latest. But I am gettting an error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist. in file`

Here is my Api Code

```
 public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::with('comment', 'user')
    ->latest()
    ->get()
    ->paginate(5);
    return response()->json([
        'status'=>200,
        'posts'=>$posts
    ]);
}
```

Kindly help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the `get` method, this is enough:

```
$posts = Post::with('comment', 'user')
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(5);
```